# Brightcove video player, detect video loaded

Tags: javascript, brightcove

I would like to know how to detect when the videoPlayer is loaded.
Basically I want to hide the selector that includes the videoPlayer and show it when the player is loaded...

I've tried this..

```
$(playerIDDiv).append('<div id="playerH" style="display:none"><object id="homesPlayer" class="BrightcoveExperience"><param name="bgcolor" value="#000" /><param name="width" value="480" /><param name="height" value="333" /><param name="playerID" value="'+playerID+'" /><param name="playerKey" value="'+playerKey+'" /><param name="isVid" value="true" /><param name="isUI" value="true" /><param name="dynamicStreaming" value="true" /><param name="wmode" value="opaque" /><param name="templateLoadHandler" value="myTemplateLoaded"><param name="includeAPI" value="true" /></object></div>');
        brightcove.createExperiences();




     function myTemplateLoaded(experienceID) {

    player = brightcove.api.getExperience(experienceID);

    modVP = player.getModule(brightcove.api.modules.APIModules.VIDEO_PLAYER);
    modExp = player.getModule(brightcove.api.modules.APIModules.EXPERIENCE);
    modCon = player.getModule(brightcove.api.modules.APIModules.CONTENT);

    modExp.addEventListener(brightcove.api.events.ExperienceEvent.TEMPLATE_READY, onTemplateReady);
}

function onTemplateReady(evt) {
  $('#playerH').show('slow');
}
```

It doesn't work at all

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I notice is that you don't call the brightcove scripts:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://admin.brightcove.com/js/BrightcoveExperiences.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://admin.brightcove.com/js/APIModules_all.js">
```

Try adding this in.  And you can check the documentation for more help [here](http://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/docs/using-javascript-flash-only-player-api#enable-api). 
Also, I believe you need to check your player in the video cloud to be sure that your web settings has "Enable ActionScript/JavaScript APIs" checked.

Comment: Yeah, the scripts were on top of the page. I miss to paste it

Found the solution, if the cotainer <div> of the player is set to display none, the onTemplateLoaded is never trigered...so I decide to set the div height and width to 0px and then in the function:

    function onTemplateReady(evt) {
      $('#playerH').height('280');
    $('#playerH').width('480');
    }

Comment: Actually you need to call BrightcoveExperiences.js, or if you need the Flash-only player API, either just BrightcoveExperiences_all.js, or both BrightcoveExperiences.js and APIModules_all.js.